# Append table with jQuery after submitting form does not display

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have an HTML where I have a table that will fill with books info that can be added with a form.

I also have a js file where I'm using jQuery (just for practice) and I have created a Book constructor for every book object that is created. Every book is stored in an array (library) and each element will be a row in the HTML table. The problem is whenever I try to append my table with a new book object after submitting the form I see the new row for 1 second and then not displaying. Probably its a DOM loading problem, but I can't find a way.

Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```js
let library=[];
let book;



function Book(title,author,number_of_pages,read){
  this.title=title;
  this.author=author;
  this.number_of_pages=number_of_pages;
  this.read=read;
}


function addBook(title,author,number_of_pages,read){
    let book=new Book(title,author,number_of_pages,read);
    library.push(book);
}

addBook("Hobbit1","Tolkien",130,"read");




$(document).ready(function(){


//Show form to add a new Book
$("#newBook").on("click",function(){
    $("form").slideDown(500);
})



$("#addBook").on("submit",function(){
    let title=$("#title").val();
    let author=$("#author").val();
    let number_of_pages=$("#number_of_pages").val();
    let read=$("#read").val();

    addBook(title,author,number_of_pages,read);
    


    
})

//Remove rows
$(document).on("click", "#delete", function(){
    
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    
      library.splice(library.findIndex(x=>x.title==$(this).attr('class')),1);


});

function showLibrary()
{
    
    library.forEach(function (item,index){
        $("#books tbody").append("<tr> <td>"+item.title+"</td> <td> "+item.author+"<td> "+item.number_of_pages+"</td> <td> "+item.read+"</td> <td> <button id=delete class="+item.title+">Delete</button> </td> </tr>");

    })
}

showLibrary();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Books</h2>

<div id="books">
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Pages</th><th>Read</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            

        </tbody>
        

    </table>

</div>


<button id="newBook">New Book</button>
<form id="addBook" hidden>
    <label>Title:</label><br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title"><br>
    <label>Author:</label><br>
    <input id="author" type="text" name="author"><br>
    <label>Number of pages:</label><br>
    <input id="number_of_pages" type="text" name="number_of_pages"><br>
    <label>Have you read this book ?:</label><input id="read" type="checkbox" name="read"><br>
    <input  type="submit" value="Add Book">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know maybe it would be better to work with pure JavaScript and not jQuery but I just want to practice a little in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems in your code:

1. You must prevent the form from submiting and refreshing the page. Use `return false` on the onsubmit for this. (thats the reason of the blank page after submission):

```html
<form id="addBook" onsubmit="return false" hidden>

</form>
```

2. After adding a book, you must call showLibrary() in order for it to appear in the table:

```js
$("#addBook").on("submit",function(){
  
    //...
    
    //...
  
    //rerender the library after book add
    showLibrary();
    
})
```

3. You must clear the table `tbody` before rerendering the library:

```js
function showLibrary()
{
   //Clear the tbody before rendering library: 
    $("#books tbody").html('');
    
    
    //...
    //...
}
```

Here is your original code, with these three updates:

```js
let library=[];
let book;



function Book(title,author,number_of_pages,read){
  this.title=title;
  this.author=author;
  this.number_of_pages=number_of_pages;
  this.read=read;
}


function addBook(title,author,number_of_pages,read){
    let book=new Book(title,author,number_of_pages,read);
    library.push(book);
}

addBook("Hobbit1","Tolkien",130,"read");




$(document).ready(function(){


//Show form to add a new Book
$("#newBook").on("click",function(){
    $("form").slideDown(500);
})



$("#addBook").on("submit",function(){
    let title=$("#title").val();
    let author=$("#author").val();
    let number_of_pages=$("#number_of_pages").val();
    let read=$("#read").val();

    addBook(title,author,number_of_pages,read);
    
    //rerender the library after book add
    showLibrary();


    
})

//Remove rows
$(document).on("click", "#delete", function(){
    
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    
      library.splice(library.findIndex(x=>x.title==$(this).attr('class')),1);


});

function showLibrary()
{
   //Clear the tbody before rendering library: 
    $("#books tbody").html('');
    
    library.forEach(function (item,index){
        $("#books tbody").append("<tr> <td>"+item.title+"</td> <td> "+item.author+"<td> "+item.number_of_pages+"</td> <td> "+item.read+"</td> <td> <button id=delete class="+item.title+">Delete</button> </td> </tr>");

    })
}

showLibrary();

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <title>Whatever</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Books</h2>

<div id="books">
    <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Pages</th><th>Read</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            

        </tbody>
        

    </table>

</div>


<button id="newBook">New Book</button>
<form id="addBook" onsubmit="return false" hidden>
    <label>Title:</label><br>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title"><br>
    <label>Author:</label><br>
    <input id="author" type="text" name="author"><br>
    <label>Number of pages:</label><br>
    <input id="number_of_pages" type="text" name="number_of_pages"><br>
    <label>Have you read this book ?:</label><input id="read" type="checkbox" name="read"><br>
    <input  type="submit" value="Add Book">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```